# How to connect mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub via Watson IoT?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, watson-iot

I'd like to make the following application.

```
1.Send a command from mosquitto_pub to Arduino device via Watson IoT.  
2.Arduino subscribes to commands.
3.Arduino publishes sensor information to mosquitto_sub via Watson IoT.
```

In order to make a simple connection test I registered mosquitto_sub on Watson as a device.

I subscribed with mosquitto_sub.

```
mosquitto_sub - h osdjco.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 1883 -u　use-token-auth -P <TOKEN> -i "d:osdjco:mosquitto:18fe34cd17S1" -t "iot-2/cmd/shot/fmt/json" -d -v
```

Next I published with the following command.

```
mosquitto_pub -i a:osdjco:mosquittopub -h osdjco.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -u "a-osdjco-xztcbezrwh" - P '<TOKEN>' -t "iot-2/cmd/shot/fmt/json" -m '{"d":{"cmd":"shot"}}' -d
```

The publish was successful but the command was not subscribed.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the topic to which your application is publishing is not correct, it should be

"iot-2/type/mosquitto/id/18fe34cd17S1/cmd/shot/fmt/json"

Check Publishing commands from below link:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/mqtt.html#mqtt

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I will proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I noticed the mistake.

I added device_type and device_id to the topic of mosquitto_pub and received a message with mosuquitto_sub.

```
mosquitto_pub -i a:osdjco:mosquittopub -h osdjco.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -u "a-osdjco-xztcbezrwh" -P '<TOKEN>' -t "iot-2/type/mosquitto/id/18fe34cd17S1/cmd/shot/fmt/json" -m '{"d":{"cmd":"shot"}}' -d
```